# Handling data packets in Node Js

Tags: node.js, tcp, header, packet

Let's say I'm reading a TCP or UDP stream in Node Js. This question basically applies to any language or platform, but how do I go about creating a header for my data layer?

I suppose I need

1. A magic set of characters to identify a header
2. A number that says the length of the packet
3. ???

I would like to future proof it and follow any "typical" data packet header structures (maybe they usually include version? protocol?) but cannot for the life of me find any great information online.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [pcapng](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/PcapNg) format. The [spec](https://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) should have everything you need if you want to look at header bytes at a deeper level. Pcap is the older format, but [has limitations](https://cloudshark.io/articles/5-reasons-to-move-to-pcapng/).

There's already a pcapng parser available, [pcap-ng-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap-ng-parser) available via npm.

If you want a general protocol analyzer, you should look at [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)

### Generate a pcapng file

In order to work with a pcapng, we need a pcapng file. Fortunately, tshark (part of Wireshark), makes this easy. We can use tshark to generate 10 packets (`-c 10`) and save to the pcapng format (`-F`).

```sh
tshark -w myfile.pcapng -F pcapng -c 10
```

### JS pcapng libraries

#### pcap-ng-parser

We can use the sample js file on the about page:

```js
# temp.js
const PCAPNGParser = require('pcap-ng-parser')
const pcapNgParser = new PCAPNGParser()
const myFileStream = require('fs').createReadStream('./myfile.pcapng')

myFileStream.pipe(pcapNgParser)
    .on('data', parsedPacket => {
        console.log(parsedPacket)
    })
    .on('interface', interfaceInfo => {
        console.log(interfaceInfo)
    })
```

### Getting info from pcapng file

#### Running sample JS

Running it on my system, we see link and interface information.

```sh
$ node temp.js
{
  linkType: 1,
  snapLen: 524288,
  name: 'en0\u0003\u0005Wi-Fi\t\u0001\u0006',
  code_12: 'Mac OS X 10.14.6, build 18G103 (Darwin 18.7.0)\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000h\u0000\u0000\u0000'
}
{
  interfaceId: 0,
  timestampHigh: 367043,
  timestampLow: 1954977647,
  data: <Buffer a8 bd 27 c8 f2 fe 6c 96 cf d8 7f e7 08 00 45 00 00 28 87 c3 00 00 40 06 e4 ba ac 1f 63 c6 8c 52 72 1a fc 3c 01 bb 6c 24 4d 01 54 03 1b 06 50 10 08 00 ... 4 more bytes>
}
... <output truncated>
```

#### Vs tshark

Depending on your use case, tshark may make more sense anyway

```sh
tshark -r myfile.pcapng -c 1 -T json
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2019-12-15",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.interface_id": "0",
          "frame.interface_id_tree": {
            "frame.interface_name": "en0",
            "frame.interface_description": "Wi-Fi"
          },
          "frame.encap_type": "1",
          "frame.time": "Dec 15, 2019 12:04:14.932076000 PST",
          "frame.offset_shift": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_epoch": "1576440254.932076000",
          "frame.time_delta": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_delta_displayed": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_relative": "0.000000000",
          "frame.number": "1",
          "frame.len": "175",
          "frame.cap_len": "175",
          "frame.marked": "0",
          "frame.ignored": "0",
          "frame.protocols": "eth:ethertype:ip:udp:db-lsp-disc:json",
          "frame.coloring_rule.name": "UDP",
          "frame.coloring_rule.string": "udp"
        },
        "eth": {
          "eth.dst": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
          "eth.dst_tree": {
...
```

Comment: Shoot, sorry. I guess my question was not clear. I am trying to create my own data protocol (like FTP or HTTP, but for something else) and wanted to see some basic examples of what packet headers look like. I suppose I can use Wireshark and investigate how other software is sending data, but it might be impossible to identify their headers.

Comment: Look at the [Sample Captures](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) in Wireshark and look at how the fields are structured in relation to the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Take a look at [Developing your own Dissector](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html) or using [Lua and Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua).

Comment: If you still have the same question, make sure to read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) as a courtesy to others before asking.